# Apollo Angular not sending request

Tags: node.js, angular, graphql, apollo-client, apollo-angular

I have a simple query (Apollo-Angular Client) to fetch some data from an GraphQL server

```
  public getQuestionBank(courseCode: string): Observable<ApolloQueryResult<{}>> {
    const query = gql`
    query GetQuestionsQuery($courseCode: String!) {
      questions(courseCode: $courseCode) {
        questions
        status
      }
    }
  `;
  console.log(`GETTING QUESTIONS FOR: ${courseCode}`);
  return this.apollo.query({
    query: query,
    variables: {
      courseCode: courseCode
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
    context: {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this.user.Token)
    }
  });
}
```

The console.log is triggered but the request is never received at the server
I use a similar type of query to login which works

```
  public login(email: string, password: string): Observable<ApolloQueryResult<{}>> {
    const query = gql`
    query TeacherLoginQuery($email: String!, $password: String!) {
      teacherLogin(email: $email, password: $password) {
        id
        email
        admin
        token
        name
        status {
          code
        }
      }
    }
  `;

  return this.apollo.query({
    query: query,
    variables: {
      email: email,
      password: password
    },
    errorPolicy: 'all',
  });
}
```

I have a morgan logger on the server and no request is received

Comment: Did you catch any errors?

Comment: Can you check if you have subscribed to `getQuestionBank()` function?

Comment: my subscription was wrong, So should i assume nothing will be emitted from an observable if the subscription is wrong ?

Comment: `my subscription was wrong` - depends, if you didnt subscribe at (no one is listening for output) then query isnt send at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, reseting the client store worked for me.

`await this.apollo.client.resetStore();`